# Virtual email addresses with a DOT in postfix

Tags: postfix

am using POSTFIX on ubuntu , i created some virtual emails but the following fails ! :

`some.email@ymdomain.com` . maybe because it has a DOT in the name ?

how can i make a virtual email with a dot ?

Comment: Anything in /var/log/mail.err?

Comment: actually no new emails i add to the virtual file are being forwarded !!! here is the log :

Comment: `Feb 15 14:33:59 server postfix/postmap[17133]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/virtual.cf: No such file or directory
Feb 15 15:29:41 server postfix/postmap[19263]: fatal: open aliases: No such file or directory
Feb 15 15:44:15 server postfix/smtpd[22035]: fatal: open database /etc/postfix/virtual_m.db: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues with having a dot and you don't need to escape it... how are you doing this, by using an aliases file or a virtual alias maps?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, users will have the same email address as their login name. To redirect emails, you either have to setup virtual address aliasing or edit your `aliases` file. Check the [Address manipulation](http://postfix.eu.org/rewrite.html) page of the Postfix documentation.

In the `aliases` or a "virtual_alias_maps" file, the format for every virtual address is:

```
First.LastName: loginname
```

Run also `man 5 aliases` on your server.